# Расширить локальную переменную на весь метод C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
    if (GetComponentInChildren<tk2dSprite>() == null)
    {
        var sprite = GetComponentInChildren<tk2dSlicedSprite>();
    }
    else
    {
        var sprite = GetComponentInChildren<tk2dSprite>();
    }
    //Вот начиная отсюда, sprite подкрашиваться красным. (does not exist)
    var joyWorldTopRight = sprite.transform.TransformPoint(sprite.GetBounds().max);
    var joyScreenTopRight = BattleGUI.Instance.GuiCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(joyWorldTopRight);
    var joyWorldBottomLeft = sprite.transform.TransformPoint(sprite.GetBounds().min);
    var joyScreenBottomLeft = BattleGUI.Instance.GuiCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(joyWorldBottomLeft);
```

Можно конечно всю нижнюю часть кода вынести в отдельный метод, либо просто продублировать - то не то, ни другое не особо хорошо выглядит - дубляж кода и лишний вызов метода на ровном месте. Есть альтернативы?

Comment: объявить до условия `if` переменную `dynamiс sprite` не вариант?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не совсем понял, это можно сделать с использования tk2dSprite и tk2dSlicedSprite?

Comment: Можно, если они наследуют от одного класса (либо реализуют один интерфейс) или, например, tk2dSlicedSprite наследует от tk2dSprite

Comment: или, в крайнем случае, sprite может иметь тип object или даже dynamic (в последнем случае надо следить за производительностью, зато не нужно делать приведение типов)

Comment: @Dmitrii dynamic - это тип языка C#, на котором вы, собственно, пишите

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет его пока в Unity. Не поддерживается.

Comment: Ой, точно, там же Mono 2.0. Был неправ, извиняюсь

Comment: @Dmitrii мде..так с этим Юнити далеко не уедешь, без поддержки некоторых вещей)) надо им по лапам-то стукнуть))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего, в вашем примере переменная - точнее, **переменные** - `sprite` существуют только внутри обработки условия. Конечно, за его пределами работа с переменными невозможна.

Так как компоненты относятся к разным типам, необходимо "подниматься" по уровням абстракций, пока не обнаружится общий для компонентов класс или интерфейс.

Согласно документации (речь ведь об ассете Toolkit2D?), спрайты в тулките наследуют классу [tk2dBaseSprite](http://www.2dtoolkit.com/docs/latest/html/classtk2d_base_sprite.html), соответственно делать нужно примерно так:

```
tk2dBaseSprite sprite;
if (GetComponentInChildren<tk2dSprite>() == null)
{
    sprite = (tk2dSlicedSprite) GetComponentInChildren<tk2dSlicedSprite>();
}
else
{
    sprite = (tk2dSprite) GetComponentInChildren<tk2dSprite>();
}
```

Comment: Опередили с верным ответом ) +1.